# action mailer rails ArgumentError in Password_resets#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I set up a basic sign in, login, sign out format for a rails app and I was going to give it a function so that if a person forgot their password they could get a email back. when I went click on submit password reset I got

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: To reset your password click the URL below.
2: 
3: <%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>
4: 
5: If you did not request your password to be reset please ignore this email and your password will stay as it is.
Rails.root: /Users/cheatermoves/nightclass/mainproject/project

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb:3:in `_app_views_user_mailer_password_reset_text_erb__3613112772785486465_70118994937040'
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:6:in `password_reset'
app/models/user.rb:17:in `send_password_reset'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

just completed rails cast 250 and was doing 274. Everything was fine until I got this problem.

here is my controllers. Password resets:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  end
end
```

sessions:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if params[:remember_me]
        cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      else
        cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      end
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

users:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

and application:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token( cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

in environments/development.rb I have

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end
end
```

user_mailer.rb file

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Password Reset"
  end
end
```

anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it? I'm using rails 3.2.14 if anyone is wondering. Thanks!

Comment: did you restart your server after adding your host into `development.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't read the part where you said that you already set your

```
config.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

my bad, sorry

Comment: You can delete your answer.